# PHP Echo Script With Contradicting Coding

Tags: javascript, php, echo

I have a website that requires a more flexible type of advertising than Adsense so I'm using JuicyAds as an alternative.

Problem is that their code uses both `"` and `'` in their scripting, which makes it awkward to echo it out using PHP.  Here's what I have:

```
$ad_header = '
<!-- JuicyAds v3.0 -->
<script async src="//adserver.juicyads.com/js/jads.js"></script>
<ins id="228912" data-width="300" data-height="262"></ins>
<script>(adsbyjuicy = window.adsbyjuicy || []).push({'adzone':228912});</script>
<!--JuicyAds END-->
';
```

As you can see here, there is a part with `id="228912"`, and also a `'adzone':`, and I'm using the `'` symbol to hold the adverts.

This is then echoed out on the page using `<?php echo $header_ad; ?>`. But this causes a conflict due to the 2 types of symbols running together.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: try escaping the quotes - or use `"` around adzone would be betterer

Comment: use `echo str_replace("'",'"',$ad_header);`?

Comment: @JaromandaX - It's really as straight forward as that? Wouldn't this affect how the ad network record statistics, or are `'` and `"` classed as being the same thing?

Comment: `'` and `"` are generally interchangeable in HTML and javascript - in fact, you don't even need ANY quotes around `adzone` now that I've looked at it again

Comment: Really? Well that's good to know. Thanks @JaromandaX. What about Ronnies answer... it would be useful for echoing out large amounts of code, but I can't find anything about `EOF123`?

Comment: `EOF123` isn't significant, it could be `HELLOWORLD` - I can't recall what that is called in PHP - got it, it's a `heredoc` or `nowdoc` - and I would recommend using either of them in this case

Comment: @JaromandaX - Just found that it's the `heredoc syntax`. Some details are at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php. Thanks again

Comment: fun fact: you can actually remove all `"` and `'` in **this** HTML/JS snippet without changing its meaning. *(only works for HTML, XHTML is more strict in these things)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ad_header = <<<'EOF123'
<!-- JuicyAds v3.0 -->
<script async src="//adserver.juicyads.com/js/jads.js"></script>
<ins id="228912" data-width="300" data-height="262"></ins>
<script>(adsbyjuicy = window.adsbyjuicy || []).push({'adzone':228912});</script>
<!--JuicyAds END-->
EOF123;
```

You can now echo out $ad_header. I understand you can manually change those `'` with a `\'` or `"` but it won't be a general purpose answer. What if you had a thousand such `'`s. Yeah, search and replace can be useful, so can be escaping. But I think this block strings are a feature added to PHP just to address that workaround. Anyways, remember to declare that EOF123 part, it must be something that is not found inside your code. I like random strings.

EDIT: As Thomas has pointed out, I just missed it, use the newdoc style over heredoc one. I have updated the answer. Thomas, hugely appreciated man!

Comment: Thanks Ronnie. For my code I'm probably just going to change the `'`'s, but this is a really good sollution for longer pieces of code.  For anyone interested in finding out more, check out http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: sidenote: like double quotes `"`, heredoc has gained some bad rep as a possible vulnerability and attack vector. So, especially when dealing with snippets in foreign programming languages, you should prefer the [nowdoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) over heredoc. It is basically the single quote version of heredoc and has been introduced in PHP 5.3.0. The very only change would be the single quotes around the starting delimiter: `$ad_header = <<<'EOF123'`

Comment: @Thomas thank you for your suggestion, the answer has been updated with newdoc style